# How to construct Codable from response data structure

Tags: ios, swift, codable, jsondecoder

How to do codable for Any & JSONNull from response data

Json Response Data

```
"userType": {
        "id": "5f18J20a21n",
        "name": "userName",
        "name_prefix": null,
        "group": []
    }
```

UserType Model Class

```
struct UserType : Codable {
    let id : String?
    let name : String?
    let namePrefix: JSONNull? // I replace JSONNull with String, Is it good way to do so?
    let group : [JSONAny?]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case namePrefix = "name_prefix"
        case group = "group"
    }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
        name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
        namePrefix = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: . namePrefix)
       // namePrefix = try values.decodeIfPresent(JSONNull.self, forKey: . namePrefix)
        group = try values.decodeIfPresent([JSONAny].self, forKey: .group)
        // Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    }
}
```

I try above code which gives an error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: What is `group` supposed to be if the array is not empty? Basically `Decodable` relies on concrete types, you cannot decode `Any`.

Comment: @vadian based on response structure group looks like array with empty [].  So do need to use generic <T> type Any for decodable.

Comment: Then you have to declare `UserType<T : Decodable> : Decodable` and `let group : [T]?`. And please consider that a generic type `T` and `Any` are two completely different things.

Comment: You obviously need to research what `group` can contain to be able to implement a solution.